# How to confirm a transaction through Merkel root in this block

Tags: hash, merkle-patricia-tries

[image]

As shown above, how to get those blue hash values and how do I determine which few hashes I need

Comment: Ethereum uses Patricia-Trie https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29292 this about block and state trie https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16932